# PHP is_array returns "1" on true and breaks on false

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I am passing a jQuery array to PHP. My call back function returns the value when it is a string, but breaks when sending an array. The break is in the PHP code.

I've tested the following:

```
$yes = array('this', 'is', 'an array');
echo is_array($yes);
```

Which returns "1".

```
$yes = "array";
echo is_array($yes);
```

Which breaks the code.

Why am I not returning "true" and "false"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
echo is_array($yes) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

If you are wondering why is that necessary, that is, why just doing `echo is_array($yes)` is not enough, check this example: http://codepad.org/PcCbvTGe

As you can see, `true` is output as `1` and `false` produces no output.

---

A test done using an `if`: http://codepad.org/OIOZLqFc

```
<?php
$yes = array("trtr");
if(is_array($yes)) {
   echo "is an array";
} else {
   echo "is not";
}
```

Comment: so, if using it for my if statment, I should be using: if (is_array($yes)==1) {//do it}

Comment: ah no, if its for that, then `if(is_array($yes)==true) { ... } else { ... }` should be enough.

Comment: @JamesDoeJr. Ok, I added an example inside an `if`. you can replace the `$yes` from that function to an string and checkout the result.

Comment: ok. pardon my naivete. I hope this was not too dumb a question. I really appreciate all of you guys for the answers. There's no web community better than this one.

Answer (score 1):

If the code you posted is straight from your text editor then the lack of a semicolon at the end of `echo is_array($yes)` is the reason its breaking.

Edit: Just to clarify you're returning true/false, just not in the form of 1 or 0. You should be using `is_array()` in conjunction with a conditional.

```
$yes = 'asdf';

if (is_array($yes)){
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Returns false

```
$yes = array('this', 'is', 'an', 'array');

if (is_array($yes)){
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Returns true

Comment: hey, just saw your edit. My original implementation was in a logical if statement. It always returned false, so I had to pick it apart.

Comment: The code appears to be breaking elsewhere, what you're doing is correct with regards to the usage of `is_array()`

Comment: I'm sure it's breaking here. commenting out that portion relieves any breakage

Answer (score 1):

```
$yes = array('this', 'is', 'an array');
echo is_array($yes);
```

output -- >`1`

as `is_array($yes)` returns `true` equivalent to `echo true;` which outputs `1`

```
$yes = "array";
echo is_array($yes);//missing semicolon
```

output(nothing) -->

as `is_array($yes)` returns `false` equivalent to `echo false;` which outputs nothing

From the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

> A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1". Boolean FALSE is
>   converted to "" (the empty string). This allows conversion back and
>   forth between boolean and string values.

so it's better if you code

```
echo (is_array($yes)) ? 'do something condition is true' : 'do something condition is false';
```

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't say this is the right usage for a ternary. I'd only recommend using it for assignments and return values. if the `true` and `false` expressions of the ternary are as long as they are in your case, I feel as though it makes for less readable code

Answer (score 0):

```
$test_array = ( (array)$var === $var )? true : false;
if( $test_array ) ...
```

or

```
function test_array( $var )
{
    return (array)$var === $var;
}
//...the anywhere else ...
if( test_array( $my_var) )...
```

if you want to display your data and its type, simply use :

```
var_dump( $my_var );
```